# Angular 2: Sticky scrollbar and ViewportScroller, scrolling to anchor element with sticky navbar

Tags: angular

I simply use the ViewportScroller to click and move to an anchor element:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-service',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent {

  constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

  public scrollToElementId(elementId: string): void {
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(elementId);
  }

}
```

```html
<div (click)="scrollToElementId('myDivToScroll')"></div>

<div id="myDivToScroll">Hello there</div>
```

That works perfectly fine.

However, I now added a sticky navbar. And that sticky navbar would always be on top of my anchor element. How can I make the scrollToAnchor-call ignore the sticky navbar height? How can this be solved in Angular 10?

Answer (score 1):

Found it out: `viewportScroller` provides a `setOffset` function which let's you adjust the viewportscroll.